# Advice for first-time, female D&D player?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, gender

I haven’t played D&D before, or anything remotely like it. I’ve been invited to join a group of players by the DM, and I accepted because he’s a good friend, but now I’m unsure.

It’s come to the time where I have to create my character and back story. I’ve chosen to play a rogue, because (as an avid reader and video gamer) I’ve always enjoyed the rogue characters. But on the rest of it, I’m unsure. I had a look through the Player’s Handbook, and I think thief is a good choice, but I have no clue for everything else.

I guess this is the main question I have to ask the community:

**What am I getting myself into, joining my first RPG group?** I’m especially concerned **whether novice girls are generally accepted** by a group of experienced male players. I know at least two of the guys I’ll be playing with are rather difficult for girls to deal with and would like advice for dealing with that.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. This looks like a few different questions which should be divided up so we can give each of them due attention. And since you have 20+ rep on another Stack, feel free to join the [chat]!

Comment: For "what am I getting myself into", these may help: [I'm at a loss with “Dungeons and Dragons.” How does one play it, anyway?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033/1204), and [What is role-playing, and where do I start?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4457/1204)

Comment: We have a *lot* of questions around this topic; try clicking the [tag:new-players] tag you included in your question to browse some (hopefully) helpful material.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and links / advice. I've read over quite a few and have a general idea of what I'm getting into.
As for creating my rouge, I might have to resort to asking on the chat, as I no longer have access to the players handbook.

Comment: Joining the chat really is a great idea. We'd love to help you with these questions, and it's a much easier format to help you in.

Comment: @Asteria Also, there is a free PDF that is plenty to create the basics of your character. You can download these ["D&D Basic Rules" here](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules).

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25563/how-do-i-as-a-dm-help-a-girl-integrate-into-a-group-of-all-male-role-players and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/how-do-i-make-my-role-playing-group-a-not-exclusively-male-one

Comment: Also, if you could add some detail on the concerns you have fitting in with the group, it’d be helpful. Either general concerns, or specifically related to the difficulties you foresee fitting in as a female gamer.

Comment: (I already edited in what we discussed in chat, but more detail would be very helpful for people looking to answer the question, and would also help with getting the question reopened.)

Comment: After the discussion in chat, I've posted the issue in a new question as advised.
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51721/dealing-with-difficult-male-players-when-youre-a-new-female-player